# How can I access a dynamic variable created in C++ from Javascript? (bound via V8)

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

Google was nice enough to explain how to [wrap C++ class methods with accessors that can be used from the V8 Javascript engine](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html#dynamic).

However, they don't mention how to determine the name of the JavaScript object that will have these accessor properties available.

**How do I tell V8 Javascript what the name of the C++ class instance (from the sample) is? Or if it already has a name, what is it?**

These two lines set up the accessors:

```
point_templ.SetAccessor(String::New("x"), GetPointX, SetPointX);
point_templ.SetAccessor(String::New("y"), GetPointY, SetPointY);
```

I assume they can be used like this from JavaScript:

```
someObject.x = someObject.y * 2;
```

How do I determine what "`someObject`" is?

I feel there is some code missing that finishes linking the C++ code with the V8 Javascript wrapper.

For example, in the sample code to [access static global variables](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html#static_global) there was a line that explicitly exposed the accessor functions to V8 JavaScript:

```
Handle<ObjectTemplate> global_templ = ObjectTemplate::New();
global_templ->SetAccessor(String::New("x"), XGetter, XSetter);
global_templ->SetAccessor(String::New("y"), YGetter, YSetter);
Persistent<Context> context = Context::New(NULL, global_templ)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the missing piece of the puzzle:

```
context->Global()->Set(String::New("p"), obj);
```

This line exposes the object wrapper `obj` created in the previous steps to V8 JavaScript's global context as the object "p." I named it "p" here, but it could be any valid JavaScript identifier. ([source](http://groups.google.com/group/v8-users/msg/0eff32185d0de843))